# Optimizing ajax created div element

Tags: javascript, dom, optimization

Creating suggestions div whenever search suggestions are available and removing whenever they aren't. To do this it is also required to check whether div is in DOM or not. This can be done using two ways.

**CASE I:**

Setting a **global** boolean variable `isDivAvailable = false;` and whenever we create div, we can set `isDivAvailable = true;` and can set `isDivAvailable = false;` when no suggestions available. So next time this flag will be checked before creating div.

**CASE II:**

By checking `isDivAvailable = document.getElementById("ajaxCreatedDiv");` statement we can judge the similar situation but this time we can not create **global** boolean variable as it always return null and also we don't need to set `isDivAvailable`.

**Inference:**

Case I:

1. Setting variable in global scope. (-1)
2. For creating div, it look up **global** boolean variable. (*No idea*)
3. No DOM parsing required. (+1)
4. It set the value boolean variable. (-1)

Case II:

1. Not setting in global scope. (+1)
2. For creating div, it look up DOM. (*No idea*)
3. For DOM lookup, parsing is required. (-1)
4. No setting of variable required. (+1)

**Winner:**

CASE I: -1 , CASE II: 1 => **CASE II**

**Confusion:**

Which one is faster?

1. **Javascript's** global scoped variable look up.
2. **HTML** DOM parsing and retriving ajaxCreatedDiv

Comment: Both will suck ..but Javascript's global scoped variable look up. will be little faster

Comment: Can you please explain..!

Comment: Traversing a DOM is indeed a heavy operation and using global scope variable is an headache for interpreter to search through all scopes chains..use  http://jsperf.com/ to test performace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which one is faster?

JavaScript variables are blazingly fast (regardless of scope). Everything that involves DOM, and especially evaluating selectors, is slooow.

However, neither is required. The boolean flag does not need to be global, it just needs to be *static* - in a scope outside of the function that uses it. And the `document.getElementById` call can be avoided by simply holding a reference to an (`id`-less) `<div>`, which is repeatedly appended/removed to the DOM. You don't even really need an extra boolean variable, just test whether `myDiv.parentNode == null` to see whether it is currently detached.

Comment: Question is prove how?

Comment: @Bergi First of all thanks for your time. I saw the results and amazed to see them, feeling enlightened.. :) And `myDiv.parentNode == null` statement will require DOM parsing, isn't it??

Comment: Parsing? No, there are no strings involved. It does require DOM access, yes, but *that* is fast. Seriously, it hardly matters: http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-var/3. Go for shorter code :-)

Comment: @Bergi What i learnt till now says, it required parsing. But yeah this time it will return boolean value. So rule of thumb promote use of JS variables instead of DOM parsing.